# Change a method that uses System.out.print() to work with System.out.println()

Tags: java

I have the following code which works perfectly fine:

```
public static void printTrain(String[][] train, int max_height) {
    // Controls the height, 0 means the top
    for (int i = 0; i < max_height; i++) {
        // Controls the wagon index
        for (int j = 0; j < train.length; j++) {
            if (j != train.length - 1)
                System.out.print(train[j][i] + " ");
            else
                System.out.print(train[j][i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

However, for my current project I am only allowed to use a special library (Terminal) which only allows me to use `Terminal.printLine(...);`.

So I have to change the method so that it only uses Terminal.printLine() <=> System.out.println().

This is how far I got:

```
public static void printTrain(String[][] train, int max_height) {
    StringBuilder trainGraphic = new StringBuilder();
    // Index for the height of a wagon
    for (int i = 0; i < max_height; i++) {
        // Wagon index
        for (int j = 0; j < train.length; j++) {
            if (j != train.length - 1) { // This means you need to print the connector
                trainGraphic.append(train[j][i]).append(" ++ ");
            } else {
                trainGraphic.append(train[j][i]).append("    ");
            }
        }
        Terminal.printLine("");
    }
}
```

No matter what I tried, it didn't work out as expected and always prints it out wrong.
How do I change the code so it only uses Terminal.printLine()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you're creating *one* `StringBuilder` for the whole method - but never actually printing the result of it. Instead, create one `StringBuilder` per line of output. It's not a big change from your original code:

```java
public static void printTrain(String[][] train, int max_height) {
    // Controls the height, 0 means the top
    for (int i = 0; i < max_height; i++) {
        // Create a StringBuilder for this specific line
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        // Controls the wagon index
        for (int j = 0; j < train.length; j++) {
            if (j != train.length - 1)
                builder.append(train[j][i] + " ");
            else
                builder.append(train[j][i]);
        }
        // Print out the line we've prepared in the StringBuilder
        Terminal.printLine(builder.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's a good idea. Thanks! Do I need the .toString() though?

Comment: @LudwigvonDrake: I don't know - because I don't know what the parameter type of `Terminal.printLine`. If it's `String`, then yes, you do. If it's `Object` then no, it's likely to be fine. But something's going to convert it to a string at some point, I suspect.

Comment: I just checked and it has `Object` as parameter. Therefore .toString() is not necessary. Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: @LudwigvonDrake Suggestion. In addition to the changes you've made, you could modify it to take a `Consumer<String>` and then call the consumer's `accept` method with each line of output, and then pass in either `System.out::println` or `Terminal::printLine` as the consumer, to easily switch between them. It would also allow you to pass in one based on a `PrintWriter` wrapped around a `StringWriter`, if you wanted to write unit tests of this method.